# How to process a dataframe column based on another dataframe column in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say that I have these two dataframes

```
df1 :   | Name|    Surname      | email   
          John      Smith         JohnSmith@gmail.com
          Jake      Smith         JakeSmith@gmail.com 
          Anna      Hendrix       Anna1994@protonmail.com      
          Kale      Kinderstone   Kinder@hotmail.com
         George     Hiddleston    GH@tonmail.com
        Patrick     Huston        Huston1990@yahoomail.com


df2 :   | Name|    Surname      | email   
          John      Smith         JSmith@ymail.com
         Hannah     Montana       HMontana@ymail.com 
          Anna      Hendrix       AHendrix@ymail.com      
          Kale      Kinderstone   KKinderstone@ymail.com
         Ivan       Gaganovitch   IG@ymail.com
        Florence     Jekins       FJekins@ymail.com
```

What I want to do is replacing some particular emails without touching the rest of the data. So, the final product I want to make is

```
df3 :   | Name|    Surname      | email   
          John      Smith         JSmith@ymail.com
          Jake      Smith         JakeSmith@gmail.com 
          Anna      Hendrix       AHendrix@ymail.com      
          Kale      Kinderstone   KKinderstone@ymail.com
         George     Hiddleston    GH@tonmail.com
        Patrick     Huston        Huston1990@yahoomail.com
```

At the beginning, I tried joining them by concatenating the names and using the column as key, but then I got stuck on how to process the column and then how to remove the df2 data.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly do you want to do? Based on your example, I would deduce, that you want to have the e-mail-adress from df2 in df1, correct?

Comment: What kind of join did you try ? on my opinion an "outer" join would give the result

Comment: Full Outer Join. But then I need to do the replacement and then get rid of the extra data acquired from join.

Comment: I think there is no builtin functionality. I would do the outer join first, then apply a withColumn and and is.null check on the e-mail adresses to merge both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the dataframes, but use `alias` on them. Then you will be able to choose between columns of the same name.

```py
df3 = (df1.alias('a')
    .join(df2.alias('b'),['Name', 'Surname'], 'left')
    .select(
        'Name',
        'Surname',
        F.coalesce('b.email', 'a.email').alias('email')
    )
)
df3.show()
# +-------+-----------+--------------------+
# |   Name|    Surname|               email|
# +-------+-----------+--------------------+
# |   Anna|    Hendrix|  AHendrix@ymail.com|
# |   Jake|      Smith| JakeSmith@gmail.com|
# |   John|      Smith|    JSmith@ymail.com|
# |Patrick|     Huston|Huston1990@yahoom...|
# | George| Hiddleston|      GH@tonmail.com|
# |   Kale|Kinderstone|KKinderstone@ymai...|
# +-------+-----------+--------------------+
```